# Save values in XML Attribute/XML Element Values of Answers for Questionneer

Tags: xml, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xml-serialization, nlp-question-answering

I am making a questioner app for Xamarin iOS iPad App.
When someone open the app, then this shows the Categories, then from Categories this will open sub categories, from sub categories this will open up a list of questions.
When Questions is opened, it will show a detail page with a list of choices and a textbox for adding answer of question.

Now the thing is, when open a detail page for question and save the answer of that particular question. Answer and choice from list need to be saved to the XML file against that question.

How I can achieve this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Categories xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <SubCategories>
    <Question QuestionTitle="I am question101" SubCategories="100" CategoryId="facilityId">
        <Checklists_Items Checklist_ItemTitle="title101" Checklist_ItemId="999" Checklist_ItemQuestion="question101" />
    </Question>
  </SubCategories>
</Categories>
```

Comment: Use models and bindings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this by doing the following:
Make a class file with all the required properties which are needed to save the values, then set the properties values of that class and serialize the class object with values into XML and Write that serialized XML string into XML file.

**Below is the sample code for object class.**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
//[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]

public partial class QuestionsCollection
{
    private string _Question;
    private string _Answer;

    public QuestionsCollection()
    {
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Question
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Question;
        }
        set
        {
            this._Question = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [XmlArrayItemAttribute("Questions", IsNullable = false)]
    public string Answer
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Answer;
        }
        set
        {
            this._Answer = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**Code to Serialize Object Class:**

```
string question = "This is first question?";
string answer = "Answer to first question";

var path1 = Path.Combine(Directory, _path);
//Setting Values
            var c = new QuestionsCollection { Question = question, Answer = answer };

//Serialization of Object Class.    
            var s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(QuestionsCollection));
            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            using (var writer = new StringWriter(sb))
            {
                try
                {
                    s.Serialize(writer, c);
//Write Serialized String to file.
                    File.WriteAllText(path1, sb.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8);

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                }
            }
```